Proper flow for fetching large "editable" data in react
I am trying to identify what would be the proper way to handle the kind of problem we face as react devs when dealing with "proper way" of fetching/managing editable data. Let me paint an exaggerated picture so that we have an idea on what is the problem.
Assumptions:

no server side rendering - developmental constraint of the project
datasets are 200+ MB large JSON files with many fields
Redux is used as an external stor
data is not "global" or "app" level (what I mean by this is, the data is only used by a SINGLE component - the editor - and no other component actually needs data access) There can be multiple instances of the editor open though.

So here are the problems im having with identifying what is the proper pattern here:

When to data fetch?
Where to "store" the fetched data

Lets start with an easier (more common) one
When to data fetch
The primary concern here is that the data needs to be available for rendering inside an "editor" which could be loaded on a page, thus we have the case of "you need data to show the page", which means that you need to handle data fetching (in case no data is present) on page reload (refresh).
But we cant use the useEffect to load this data, that is an anti-pattern.
And data being present is not a result of a user "clicking" some handler.
The obvious answer would be, preload the data with SSR for the case of "refresh" / "initial" page load - which cannot be done due to constraints. So how to resolve this ?
Additionally, this still leaves the issue of user loading up on a different page and navigating to this page. Obviously we do not want to couple the <link> navigation to datafetching, which leaves me kinda stumped as to what is the pattern.
I just do not see a way to decouple "navigation" and data fetching without the use of useEffect to fetch the data.
Where to store the data
Now this one is bit more.... complicated.
The "editor" should be compared to a form of sorts. It has its own model which it works with and updates and it does not interact with an external storage for this purpose. It can "preload" / "load" the data, but once loaded, it uses its own state to work with any changes that may be done by the user. In other words, the EDITOR is where the data is ultimately stored. However....
Editor cannot "fetch" the data, so something else has to "pass" data into it. This can be done through a preload property on initial render or through the use of ref.current.load method afterwards. Both of these come with their own problems.
Preload
For this to work, it must be passed as a prop during the initial rendering of the Editor, this means that the data must already be loaded when this happens or in other words:
const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState()


  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData().then(setData)
  }, [])


  if(!data) return null // or some loader...

  return <Editor preload={data}/>
}

But this leads to "duplicated" data being stored, one in Page state, one inside the editor. Same thing is the case for external storage, such as Redux. Alternatively, one could use the editor's ref to "load" the state as such:
Loading after render
const Page = () => {
  const ref = useRef()


  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData().then(ref.current.load)
  }, [])

  return <Editor ref={ref}/>
}

This way we skip the local state, however we have to "render" the editor for us to access the ref and since we are downloading 200MB we will have a blank editor with no data for a while, alongside a slew of other issues with conciling loaded data and whatever happened within the editor. Some loader within the editor itself could prevent this, but editor is an abstraction that is unaware of "loading" and could also be "opened" with no data in case you are "creating" rather than "editing" a data-set. Obviously this aint a solution either.
What would be the best approach to solve these two issues.

The preload option should work.
It may not lead to duplicated data provided the same state in Page component is referenced from Editor as well. For that the state setter setData in Page must also be passed as another props to Editor.
Code below is from your post:
const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState()


  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData().then(setData)
  }, [])


  if(!data) return null // or some loader...

  return <Editor preload={data}/>
}

The point is objects are passed by reference whereas primitives are passed by value. Please see the below sample code which demoes the same.
App.js
import { useState } from 'react';

const Page = () => {
  const [objectState, setObjectState] = useState({ property1: 'someValue1' });
  const [primitiveState, setPrimitivetate] = useState('someValue1');

  return (
    <Editor
      preload1={objectState}
      preload2={objectState}
      preload3={primitiveState}
      preload4={primitiveState}
    />
  );
};

function Editor(props) {
  console.log(
    `Props for objects are called by reference : props.preload1 === props.preload2 ? ${
      props.preload1 === props.preload2 ? true : false
    }`
  );
  console.log(
    `Props for primitives are called by value :props.preload3 === props.preload4 ? ${
      props.preload3 === props.preload4 ? true : false
    }`
  );
  console.log('Additional information');
  console.log(
    `type of props.preload1 and props.preload2 : ${typeof props.preload1} and ${typeof props.preload2}`
  );
  console.log(
    `type of props.preload3 and props.preload4 : ${typeof props.preload3} and ${typeof props.preload4}`
  );
  return 'Done';
}

export default Page;

Console logs generated by the code:
// Props for objects are called by reference : props.preload1 === props.preload2 ? true
// Props for primitives are called by value :props.preload3 === props.preload4 ? true

// Additional information
// type of props.preload1 and props.preload2 : object and object
// type of props.preload3 and props.preload4 : string and string

Therefore please wrap the data inside an object if it is not so now, and pass it to Editor as its props. This would not duplicate data in memory as we have seen by the above demo. However, if the data is string - primitive, yes, it would duplicate data in memory.
useEffect in Page component may be a useful event to fetch data
In continuing with the above understanding, date fetching in Page component via its useEffect may be the most feasible option to implement the preload, this is especially true under the case that the App has no scope for backend rendering. Navigating to another page while the current page's fetch is under progressing is a common scenario, which has been handled through the use of simple flags. The clean up function of useEffect will come in our rescue here. The following code quoted from React documentation does the same.
A sample code from React documentation Fetching data:
useEffect(() => {
  let ignore = false;

  async function startFetching() {
    const json = await fetchTodos(userId);
    if (!ignore) {
      setTodos(json);
    }
  }

  startFetching();

  return () => {
    ignore = true;
  };
}, [userId]);

Lastly, if the state is further lifted up - lifted up to the common parent component to both Page and Editor, then the performance of the App upon accessing the same page frequently - opened and closed, may be also enhanced. Surely using Context in such case will ease its implementation.
